# How to specify the regex string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following 2 strings of train station IDs (showing the direction of travel) separated by "-".

```
String A (strA):
NS1-NS2-NS3-NS4-NS5-NS7-NS8-NS9-NS10-NS11-NS13-NS14-NS15-NS16-NS17-NS18-NS19-NS20-NS21-NS22-NS23-NS24-NS25-NS26-NS27

String B (strB):
NS27-NS26-NS25-NS24-NS23-NS22-NS21-NS20-NS19-NS18-NS17-NS16-NS15-NS14-NS13-NS11-NS10-NS9-NS8-NS7-NS5-NS4-NS3-NS2-NS1
```

I want to find out which of String A or B contains stations "NS4" followed by "NS1" (answer should be String B).
My current code as follows:

```
searchStr = ".*NS4-.*NS1(-.*|)"
re.search(searchStr, strA)
re.search(searchStr, strB)
```

But the result keep returning a match in String A.
May I know how to specify '**searchStr**' in order to match only String B?

Comment: regular expressions is **not** the correct tool for this job

Comment: "NS4-NS10" will match your regular expression.

Comment: Hi Jarrod, so should I tokenize it into a list for the search?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The question appears clear to me.  Use `NS4-.*NS1($|-)` as regexp.  Should work.

Comment: I was about to answer this, use this regex: `NS4(?=.*?NS1(?!\d))` It says that NS1 must follow NS4, but a digit cannot follow NS1. It will work.

Comment: Hi Alfe and Vasili, appreciate your help! I had actually rewrote my code to tokenize the String A/B into lists and use their indices to obtain my desired result. However I have also duplicate the code to test out both of your regex, ran the 3 functions 100k times, and Alfe's solution is marginally faster. Both better than using the tokenizer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do it: tokenizing and improving the regex.

### Tokenizing

```
tokA = strA.split('-')
tokB = strB.split('-')

print('NS4' in tokA and tokA.index('NS1') > tokA.index('NS4'))
print('NS4' in tokB and tokB.index('NS1') > tokB.index('NS4'))

# False
# True
```

### Regex

```
import re
pattern = '(^|-)NS4.+NS1(-|$)'
print(re.search(pattern, strA) is not None)
print(re.search(pattern, strB) is not None)

# False
# True
```

### Performance

```
Tokenization: 2.3072939129997394
Regex: 11.138173280000046
```

But if you really need performance, I'm sure there are faster ways. Even the tokenization method does multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to tokenizing, you could use the following expression.

[`NS4(?=.*?NS1(?!\d))`](http://regex101.com/r/tX3wH4)

**It literally means:**

1. The characters "NS4" literally.
2. Followed by any characters, until it finds NS1.
3. NS1 cannot be followed by a digit.

---

To educate readers as to what I've used:

`(?=)` **is a Positive Lookahead.**

- Whatever you place inside this token must be found for the match to be `True`.
- I placed `.*?` to match anything, **as few times as possible** using the `?` quantifier, followed by NS1 since that is what we want to find.

`(?!)` **is a Negative Lookahead**

- Whatever you place inside this token, as you might guess, must NOT be found for the match to be `True`.
- I placed a digit in here, so that things like NS10 or NS11 or NS19 are never matched.